# Saving form data into text file from html

Tags: php, jquery, html

My task is to display the save HTML form data in text file using php script .
If the user clicks "yes" button, the dataset field will be enabled, if"no", token number field will be enabled.
the user will be navigated to the page depending on his radio button selection.
Please take a look at my code and let me know where I am going wrong.thanks in advance
Here is my HTML

```
<form method="post" action="Input1.php" name="form">
<label> New Data set: </label>
<input type="radio" name="url" value="NetOptInput2.html" id="ex1" required/> Yes
<input type="radio" name="url" value="NetOptResult2.html" id="ex2" required/> No
<br><br><br>
<label>Dataset description:
</label>
<input type="text" name="Dataset" id="field1" size="30" placeholder="" readonly><br><br><br>
<label>Token Number : </label><input type="text" name="Token Number" id="field2"   size="6" placeholder="" readonly><br><br><br>

<div style="text-align: center"><br>
<input type="Submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="submit">
<div class="spacer"></div> 
</form>
```

and here is my JQuery in the  of html:

```
<!-- this function navigates user according to the radio button selection-->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

 $('form').submit(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
window.location = $('input[type=radio]:checked').val();
});
});
</script>
<!--This function disables the Token Number form if the user clicks "yes" radio button and disables Dataset if "No"-->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$("#ex1, #ex2").change(function(){
    $("#field1, #field2").val("").attr("readonly",true);
    if($("#ex1").is(":checked")){
        $("#field1").removeAttr("readonly");
        $("#field1").focus();
    }
    else if($("#ex2").is(":checked")){
        $("#field2").removeAttr("readonly");
        $("#field2").focus();   
    }
});
});
</script>
```

Here is my PHP:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST[submit'])) { 
$Dataset = $_POST['Dataset'];
$Token number = $_POST['Token Number'];
$data = "$Dataset | $Token Number\n";
$file = "input.txt"; 

$fp = fopen($file, "a") or die("Couldn't open $file for writing!");
fwrite($fp, $data) or die("Couldn't write values to file!"); 

fclose($fp); 
$message = "Saved to $file successfully!";
}
?>
```

Comment: You're missing a quote in `$_POST[submit']`. Is that in the real code or just a typo in the question?

Comment: You're missing a quote in the PHP, first line !

Comment: thanks for looking..I added quote,but, still its not working.it was just a typo

Comment: Since you have `event.preventDefault()`, the form never gets submitted when the user clicks the `Submit` button. So your PHP will never be run.

Comment: If i need to run the jquery and also PHP script, do i have to remove event.preventDefault()? if i delete that, would the jquery work? please suggest the changes to make both of them work..thanks for helping

Comment: If you remove `preventDefault`, it will submit the form, but won't do the `window.location` redirect. You can't do both. You should probably have the PHP do the redirect using `header("Location: <newURL>")`.

Comment: please help me with this..i need to execute both jquery and php with the same submit button action.i dont know how to do that

Comment: Is there anyother way to combine these two functions in one submit button action?

Answer (score 0):

A few things I see wrong at first glance...

`if (isset($_POST[submit'])) {` - You're missing a ' before submit `$_POST['submit']`

Variables can only be one word, so `$Token number` won't work.

It's also a best practice (perhaps a PHP requirement, not sure) to start variables with lowercase letter. And, for that matter, the names of your posted form fields as well.